# Select All Nodes that have been searched for (that are visible)?

Tags: react-dropdown-tree-select

Is there any way to select all of the nodes that have been searched for? I can see that there is a way to select all of the nodes but I want to be able to 'Select All' but only for the nodes that I have searched for?

Answer (score 0):

There is `onChange` method with `selectedNodes` propery for that. See [documentation](https://github.com/dowjones/react-dropdown-tree-select#onchange).

Example:

```
function onChange(currentNode, selectedNodes) {
    console.log(selectedNodes)
}
```